# Join from Age to AgeGroup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a Clients table with a field named "Age" that is a computed column.

I then have an AgeGroup table where it has the ranges within. What would be the best way of joining these two tables below so I can get the correct AgeGroup?

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you share your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing magical happening here, just do a join with `BETWEEN` for the `ON` condition.  Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive of both end points, which works nicely with your data, whose age ranges do not overlap.

```
SELECT c.name,
       a.AgeGroup
FROM clients c
INNER JOIN AgeGroup a
    ON c.age BETWEEN a.StartRange AND a.EndRange
```